# Replace String Two Different Parts

Tags: string, excel, replace, vba

I am extracting a column of data from a range of filenames. All my filenames are strings in the form:

`Temporary PSD Report 'Month' 2011.xls`

I am using `Replace` to extract the month from each, at the moment I am doing it in two stages which works but it seems a bit clumsy. Is there a way to use some kind of `AND` for multiple replacements in the same string?

```
    Dim strfilename As String
    Dim mnth As String
    Dim mnthshrt As String

    mnth = Replace(strfilename, "Temporary PSD Report ", "")
    mnthshrt = Replace(mnth, " 2011.xls", "")
```

I've tried using `&` and `AND` to reference both parts to be removed but it either has no effect on the original string or produces an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also split the string at each space character and take the 4th word (index starts at 0):

```
s = "Temporary PSD Report 'Month' 2011.xls"
mth = Split(s, " ")(3)
```

Comment: Very clean, thanks. Out of interest is it possible to do this with some kind of multiple replace?

Comment: @AlistairWeir As far as I know, no - but someone might know better (for example by using some sort of regex).

Comment: +1 Yes even I would have gone with split. But I would have used `'` as a delimiter and split it twice for example `Debug.Print Split(Split(s, "'")(1), "'")(0)`

Comment: Mmm... in that case one split seems enough to me! I did not split on `'` as I thought it was there to highlight the month rather than actually present in the real name.

Comment: Assylias is right the ' was only used in the example however useful to know if situation did arise.

Comment: Hope its ok to discuss this further here. Hoe would we go about solving this if the filename contained no spaces?

Comment: @siddharth "Even I..." Do you find `split` has limitations in other instances?

Comment: I presumed by your language that you prefer to avoid using `split` unless there was no better solution.